# Python - group pandas dataframe by 10 years and by month and calculate mean

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

In my pandas dataframe I have daily data from 2021 to 1959 (only for months April-September) and I want to calculate the mean for 10 year periods (2021 - 2012, 2011-2002, 2001-1902 and so on) for all my columns. Then I also want the mean over those 10 year periods but additionally grouped by month.

Here is my dataframe:
[image]

What I tried so far:

```
df_grouped = df_clean.groupby([(df_clean.index.year), (df_clean.index.month)]).mean()
```

But that is only for each year and not for 10 year periods.

And this groups by decade but doesnt start at 2021 and doesn´t group by month:

```
df_clean.groupby((df_clean.index.year//10)*10).mean()
```

I also need to do the same with the standarddeviation and at the end I want to plot everything.

Help would be gladly appreciated.

Best,
Lena

Comment: Hi! You could create an additional column in the dataframe with the groups of the decades. For example, a column specifying "decade_1" for all the rows between 2021 - 2012, "decade_2" for 2011-2002, and so on. Then use this column for grouping with `.groupby`.

Comment: That worked, thanks a lot! Do you know how I could plot for each decade seperately the variables against the month without splitting the dataframe into chunks?

Comment: Not sure if I follow what you are after. I guess it depends on the kind of plot you have in mind. You could have many subplots (one per decade), each one with 12 (months) in x-axis and the single variable in y-axis. Or you could have all the variables together in y-axis. Both `matplotlib` and `seaborn`libraries can help you here.